# jQuery .post returns html?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, http-post

I have a form that I want to be submitted without page refresh, manipulate the Inputed value and return something. For this i use HTML, jQuery and PHP like so:

The Form:

```
<form id="disabledForm" class="d3nAskerFrom">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Ask Me!" class="d3nAskerInput" autocomplete="off" />
    <div class="invisibleDiv"><div class="textSizeTest"></div></div>
    <input type="submit" class="invisibleSubmit" />
</form>
```

The jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#disabledForm').submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault();return false; });
    $('.d3nAskerFrom').submit(function(e){ var task = $('.d3nAskerInput').val();think(task);e.preventDefault();return false; });
</script>
```

The think(task) function (and answer(data) which think(task) uses):

```
function think(task){
    $.post('php/think.php',{ "task":task }, function(da){ answer(da); });
    $('.d3nAskerInput').val('');
}
function answer(text){
    alert(text);
}
```

The think.php file:

```
<?php

$task = stripslashes($_POST['task']);

// Do the magic

echo($task);exit();

?>
```

Now, when I submit the form with any input, there are times when I get an alert as this one:

```
<html><body><script>document.cookie='kkkkkkk=9eb6ed5bkkkkkkk_9eb6ed5b; path=/';window.location.href=window.location.href;</script></body></html>
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: FYI in $('.d3nAskerFrom').submit(..) put the preventDefault before the return.

Comment: yeah.. that's yet a minor error committed because of my lack of attention (EDITED)

Comment: Why do you have two different event handlers tied to the same element doing conflicting things?

Comment: Is that really the only contents of the think.php file?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy : Yes, only those lines (is only a test system, which is obviously failing at the moment).

Comment: @MikeBrant : I don't understand, where exactly you think things may be in conflict?

Comment: You have `.submit()` handlers defined for this form based on both the form's id and its class.  What is the point of executing two handlers when all one of them does is `preverntDefault()`?

Comment: @MikeBrant : Yes, in the future I'll have more forms with the ID="#disabledForm", so, I'd like all of them to submit without refreshing. On d3nAskerForm I've put the preventDefault in there only for a precaution.. to be sure it won't submit.

Comment: @d3nm4k You must have a unique ID for each form.  If you had multiple forms with that ID, the handler would only be attached to the first one in the DOM as jQuery expects ID's to be unique. You should simply make it another class is this is the desired behavior.  I..e `<form class="disabledForm d3nAskerFrom">` and `$('.disabledForm').submit(...)`

Comment: @MikeBrant : Opps.. forgot about that.. excuse my lack of attention.. it's just frustrating I get that alert, I don't think, while I don't have more tags with the same ID ,that the preventDefault generates that error.